# How to enable full version for Actions on Google through Subscription

Tags: actions-on-google, subscription

I want to accept subscriptions from users who are interested in our full version for my Action-on-Google. I have  implemented account-linking and my targeted users are from India.

How can we give the full version on Google Action once we receive the payment on our website?  Any workaround is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you have [account linking](https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity), you can link the user's account between your service and Google so that you can perform a lookup of the user's Google account and see if they have a subscription through your service.

Additionally there is a feature that lets people [request and pay for subscriptions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/transactions/digital/dev-guide-digital-subscriptions) through the Google Assistant, but it's not available in India today.